# Can I put a RedirectResult into a view link?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have the following situation:

Into a view I define a link in this way:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Edit", "Vulnerability", new { id = Model.Id })"   data-mini="true"  data-inline="true"   data-role="button"  >Annulla</a>
```

As you can see when the user click the link it is executed the **Edit()** method ot the **VulnerabilityController** class passing and Id value

Ok, this works fine but in this view I want have something like I have in a controller, this thing:

```
return new RedirectResult(Url.Action("Edit", "Vulnerability", new { id = vulnId }) + "#tab-2");
```

As you can see in this second version I always call the **Edit()** method of the **VulnerabilityController** class but the value of Id variable is something like **"1234#tab-2"**

Can I do something like this in my view and not only in my controller?

Comment: Please explain in words, not code, what you want to do. You want to "redirect from a view", in other words put a hyperlink in HTML?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to render (include) the results of some action inside your View you can use `Html.Action`:

```
@Html.Action("Edit", "Vulnerability", new { id = vulnId + "#tab-2" })
```

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee703423%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

For doing this using Razor Syntax, you can try like this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Annulla", "Edit", "Vulnerability", new { id = Model.Id }, 
new{ @data_mini="true", @data_inline="true", @data_role="button"})
```